# Redirecting to home in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Redirect to home. I opened different App from my App using intent. When I click back it was redirecting to my application. But at that time I want to close that App or redirect me to home. I tried with `finish()` and `destroy()`. But those are not working ?

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    nextIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,package_running_cls));
                    NotFirst.this.finish();
                    startActivity(nextIntent);
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: When you open other app at that time finish current app and lanuch new app you want. Then when you press back button it destroy current app and your last app destroyed when you start intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moveTaskToBack(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29).

This will hide your application until the user wants to use it again.

The longer answer starts with another question: why do you want to kill your application?

The Android OS handles memory management and processes and so on so my advice is just let Android worry about this for you. If the user wants to leave your application they can press the Home button and your application will effectively disappear. If the phone needs more memory later the OS will terminate your application then.

As long as you're responding to lifecycle events appropriately, neither you nor the user needs to care if your application is still running or not.

So if you want to hide your application call moveTaskToBack() and let Android decide when to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

If finish() is not working you should override onBackpressed() method and in onbackpressed you can use intent to go to your HomeActivity like this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent in=new Intent(this,YourHomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        this.finish();
    }
```

try this, it may help you.